# Generate p:tabs from Java List

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create Primefaces tabs from Java List. I tested this code:

```
<p:tabView value="#{DatacenterProfileController.data}" var="listItem">
    <p:tab title="#{listItem.name}">
        <ui:insert>
            <ui:include src="#{listItem.page}" />
        </ui:insert>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

---

```
private List<PagesObj> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public class PagesObj {

        private String name;
        private String page;

        public PagesObj(String name, String page) {
            this.name = name;
            this.page = page;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPage() {
            return page;
        }

        public void setPage(String page) {
            this.page = page;
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void datagenerate(){
        dataList.add(new PagesObj("General", "DCProfileTabGeneral.xhtml"));
        dataList.add(new PagesObj("Zones", "DCProfileTabZones.xhtml"));
        dataList.add(new PagesObj("Generators", "DCProfileTabGenerators.xhtml"));
        dataList.add(new PagesObj("HVAC", "DCProfileTabHVACs.xhtml"));
    }

    public List<PagesObj> getdata() {

        return dataList;
    }
```

But for some reason the body of the tabs is not loaded properly - I get empty body tab maybe because the file is not found. Can you help me to solve the problem, please?

Comment: are you sure datagenerate is being called at right time? (even though I see its marked as postconstruct). Try to move the population in "getData" by checking the size of the array, populate and then return to eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Would you post code example of your idea?

Comment: public List<PagesObj> getdata() {
        if(dataList.size() == 0) { dataList.add(.....)};
        return dataList;
    }
Instead of populating your list in 'datagenerate' populate it in getdata. If this works, then the issue was in populating the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that this is an issue, using include with tabView [Issue 4051](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4051)

So this is working example:

```
<p:tabView  id="tabW">
    <c:forEach items="#{DatacenterProfileController.data}" var="listItem"> 
        <p:tab title="#{listItem.name}">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <ui:include src="#{listItem.page}.xhtml"  />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
    </c:forEach>
</p:tabView>
```

Took from this [primefaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21807)

Answer (score 1):

Can not test it right now, but i think that **ui:insert** is not needed. Therefore your code should be

```
<p:tabView value="#{DatacenterProfileController.data}" var="listItem">
    <p:tab title="#{listItem.name}">
         <ui:include src="#{listItem.page}" />
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Also ensure that this page is in the same directory as the included pages