# Using <p:ajax> in JSF UIRepeat prevents rendering of component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a jsf, where I want to show a list of checkboxes. If I create it like in the following example, the checkboxes are rendered correctly.

```
<p:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{scheduleConfigBean.selectedMonthType == 1}" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 45px">
  <ui:repeat var="monthDay" value="#{scheduleConfigBean.monthDays}">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{monthDay.checked}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{monthDay.name}" />
  </ui:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>
```

But when I add a ajax event listener to each checkbox, the panel is not rendered any longer. What is my problem here?

```
<p:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{scheduleConfigBean.selectedMonthType == 1}" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 45px">
  <ui:repeat var="monthDay" value="#{scheduleConfigBean.monthDays}">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{monthDay.checked}">
      <p:ajax listener="#{scheduleConfigBean.updateMonthlyButtonState}" update="saveBtn" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:outputText value="#{monthDay.name}" />
  </ui:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I think my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14120506/1692632) should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Darka, his answer gives me the solution.

```
<p:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{scheduleCreate.selectedMonthType == 1}" style="width: 500px; margin-top: 45px">
  <c:forEach items="#{scheduleCreate.monthDays}" var="monthDay" varStatus="status">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{monthDay.checked}" style="margin-left: 8px">
      <p:ajax listener="#{scheduleCreate.updateButton}" update="saveBtn" />
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
  </c:forEach>
</p:outputPanel>
```